# Vector search Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, r

I have the following problem. Say I have a vector:

```
v = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,...]
```

I want to sequentially sample points from the vector, that have an absolute maginute difference higher than a threshold from a previously sampled point. So say my threshold is 2.

I start at the index 1, and sample the first point 1. Then my condition is met at v[3], and I sample 3 (since 3-1 >= 2). Then 3, the new sampled point becomes the reference, that I check against. The next sampled point is 5 which is v[5] (5-3 >= 2). Then the next point is 1 which is v[6] (abs(1-5) >= 2).

Unfortunately my code in R, is taking too long. Basically I am scanning the array repeatedly and looking for matches. I think that this approach is naive though. I have a feeling that I can accomplish this task in a single pass through the array. I dont know how though. Any help appreciated. I guess the problem I am running into is that the location of the next sample point can be anywhere in the array, and I need to scan the array from the current point to the end to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see a way this can be done without a loop, so here is one:

```
my.sample <- function(x, thresh) {
   out <- x
   i <- 1
   for (j in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
      if (abs(x[i]-x[j]) >= thresh) {
         i <- j
      } else {
         out[j] <- NA
      }
   }
   out[!is.na(out)]
}

my.sample(x = c(1:5,1:4), thresh = 2)
# [1] 1 3 5 1 3
```

Comment: I'm thinking there may be an approach using `outer` and `which(...,arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Comment: Possibly, but from a complexity point of view, my algorithm is linear while `outer` is O(n^2). I could imagine an efficiently coded O(n^2) algorithm making good use of R (vectorization, etc.) could be faster than mine, but not as `n` becomes large.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop using a bit of recursion:

```
vsearch = function(v, x, fun=NULL) {
  # v: input vector
  # x: threshold level

  if (!length(v) > 0) return(NULL)

  y = v-rep(v[1], times=length(v))
  if (!is.null(fun)) y = fun(y)

  i = which(y >= x)

  if (!length(i) > 0) return(NULL)
  i = i[1]

  return(c(v[i], vsearch(v[-(1:(i-1))], x, fun=fun)))
}
```

With your vector above:

```
> vsearch(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4), 2, abs)
[1] 3 5 1 3
```